# rails 4: i can not install meta search gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, meta-search

i have written in the gem file -

```
 gem "meta_search", :git => "git://github.com/ernie/meta_search.git"
```

but getting this error message -

```
  In Gemfile:
    meta_search (>= 0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (~> 3.1) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (4.0.0)
```

this is the link of my gem lock file - http://pastebin.com/d5ydNJ0B

how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a very bad habit to post questions on GitHub AND on StackOverflow!

If you had read the issues on GitHub you would have seen that meta_search is not compatible with Rails 4 and that it's successor [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) should be used instead.

Comment: sorry. i will not do this same mistake again.